# Как поменять ассоциации для множества файлов в Linux?

Tags: linux, mime

На данный момент у меня установлено 2 текстовых редактора, которыми я пользуюсь - Code и Sublime. Первый я использую как IDE - только для работы, потому что он относительно медленно запускается. А второй более быстрый, по этому используется именно как текстовый редактор, чтобы что-то по-быстрому открыть, поправить и закрыть.

Собственно проблема в том, что сейчас для всех текстовых файлов назначен Code и я хочу поменять его на Sublime, но mime-типов очень много, через GUI менять замучаюсь, он к тому же глючный, постоянно мотает список вверх. Хотелось бы узнать, в каких файлах это можно поправить. Смотрел в `~/.local/share/applications`, там никаких записей о Code нет.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например, с помощью программы *xdg-mime* (или любым другим подручным средством, способным записывать информацию в конф. файл (`~/.local/share/applications/{mimeapps.list,defaults.list}`)).

---

посмотреть текущую ассоциацию:

```
$ xdg-mime query default <mime-тип>
```

пара запросов (данные приведены из моей системы):

```
$ xdg-mime query default application/x-abiword
libreoffice-writer.desktop
$ xdg-mime query default application/rtf
libreoffice-writer.desktop
```

чтобы назначить ассоциацию:

```
$ xdg-mime default <имя>.desktop <mime-тип> ...
```

к примеру, на программу *vim*:

```
$ xdg-mime default vim.desktop application/x-abiword application/rtf
```

проверяем:

```
$ xdg-mime query default application/x-abiword
vim.desktop
$ xdg-mime query default application/rtf
vim.desktop
```

а вот как это всё записалось в файл конфигурации:

```
$ cat ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list 
[Default Applications]
application/x-abiword=vim.desktop
application/rtf=vim.desktop
```

---

посмотреть все текущие закешированные ассоциации можно в файле `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`

Comment: Спасибо! Но если честно, я надеялся что есть такой файл, где все эти ассоциации уже сопоставлены и я просто заменю Code на Sublime, без составления списка типов. Почему-то на данный момент `xfce4-mime-settings` показывает, что все текстовые файлы открываются через Code, но ни в `mimeinfo.cache`, ни в `mimeapps.list` этих записей нет! Я смотрел как в `~/.local/share/applications`, так и в `/usr/share/applications`. Там есть много записей о VLC и GIMP, но именно Code вшит каким-то другим, непонятным мне способом.

Comment: информация собирается из *.desktop файлов и кэшируется. кстати, если мне склероз не изменяет, там, у freedesktop-овцев и по поводу места кэширования «не всё так однозначно» (помимо всего остального бардака, разведённого ими самими и усиленного разработчиками de и мэйнтэйнерами дистрибутивов). поройтесь сами в их писаниях, если есть желание. начать можно, например, с этой спецификации: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/shared-mime-info-spec/

Comment: Всё, разобрался! :) Все эти mime-типы были записаны одной единственной строкой - `text/plain=code.desktop`. Например, всякие `application.json` и тому подобные типы "наследуют" от `text.plain`.

Comment: в кэше-то хоть эта ассоциация присутствовала? или это тоже была «уличная фридесктоповская магия»?

Comment: в кэше `text/plain` и был установлен в `code.desktop`. Кроме него ещё `inode/directory`, больше ничего. Но в результате поменялось более сотни mime-типов!

Answer (score 0):

Пробовал по вашим инструкциям, и чуть не съехала крыша. Взял, и в Double Commander правой клавишей: -Открыть с помощью - (там предлагается список применимых программ) выбираю -другое, и уже теперь одну из прог этого же списка. Всё!!!